# Mysql workbench reverse engineer relationship

Tags: mysql-workbench, reverse-engineer

I've been trying to create a EER diagram from a MySql script. I've used the appropriate option in MySQL workbench (`Import > Reverse Engineer MySQL Script`)

However, the relationships are not shown, even though the tables are connected via **FOREIGN KEY** constraints.

Is there an option I'm missing ?

Answer (score 0):

Check the type of your tables. The relationship between tables can be shown for InnoDB tables but not for MyISAM.